# what happened to gtk_source_iter_forward_search in gtksourceview-3.0

Tags: gtk, gtksourceview

I've looked at the [GtkSourceView 3 Reference Manual](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/3.0/), and I've googled for a while, but I cannot find any mention of why gtk_source_iter_forward_search was dropped from gtksourceview or what should be used instead.

I've also looked at [the features link at the gtksourceview website](http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/features.html) where it lists as a feature: Caseless UTF-8 compliant search.

I've looked at the gedit source ver 3.2.6 (since I know they use gtksourceview), but they seem to be using gedit_document_search_forward, which I'm guessing comes from some other library.  So my question is, what happened to the search capabilities in gtksourceview?  Is there another library that provides similar functionality to gtk_source_iter_forward_search, or is it now done another way within gtksourceview?

I originally wrote my editor in gtksourceview-2.0, now I am rewriting it using gtksourceview-3.0, and I have an established search forward function based on the gtk_source_iter_forward_search function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always browse the source if you want to know these things. I found in [this commit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/commit/?id=d83f64f08eeb9aff5815a8b27684625c679066bc) that `GtkSourceIter` was removed because the functionality was moved to `GtkTextIter`.

Comment: thank you.  Although, I would argue that you shouldn't have to browse the source to find out such things.  It ought to be listed as a change in the reference manual, and it should no longer be listed as a feature of gtksourceview if it is now a feature of gtk+.  If only we lived in a perfect world. :) Your point is taken and I will search the source in the future, given a similar situation.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right about them not listing it as a feature, but I don't think that the manual should be cluttered with everything that was ever removed ;-) Perhaps you should submit a patch to add a small note in the documentation of `GtkSourceBuffer` that `GtkSourceIter` no longer exists?

Comment: out of genuine curiosity, do you know why there are no release notes for any of the gnome projects?  This would be the place to put that info, and it was btw the first place I went searching.

Comment: There usually are. Look on the GNOME FTP site, along with the tarballs there should also be `gtksourceview-3.0.4.changes` files. These are the release notes for each new version. Not especially easy to browse through though.